# Using variables for name and arguments to create a new instance of a class in PHP

Tags: php, class, variables

I'm trying to call a class function that creates a new instance of a subclass.

I'm doing this inside a foreach loop with the following variables for the sub class name and arguments:

```
$classname = 'Element_Radio';
$classargs = array( $a, $b ); //Might have up to 4 arguments
```

Here's the original line of code I'm trying to execute, without any of the above variables:

```
$form->addElement(new Element_Radio($required, $required, $optional_array, $optional_array);
```

So first I tried:

```
$form->addElement( new $classname ($classargs) );
```

But I think I need something like this:

```
$form->addElement( call_user_func_array(new $classname,$classargs) );
```

Either way, I'm getting errors of:

> "Warning: Missing argument 2 for Element::__construct() ..."

So it looks like the arguments are getting passed in as one array variable, and not separately.

I ended up writing a bunch of if statements to just make the function call depending on the values of `$classargs`, but I'm wondering if there is a programmatic way of doing what I want without the IFs.

EDIT - SOLUTION with the code I added to account for the fact that my array of arguments was a multidimensional array that didn't have all numeric indexes. The splat operator (...) only works with an array with numeric indexes.

```
$classname = 'Element_Radio';
$classargs = array();

if ( isset( $a ) ) { array_push($classargs, $a); }
if ( isset( $b ) ) { array_push($classargs, $b); }
if ( isset( $c ) ) { array_push($classargs, $c); }
if ( isset( $d ) ) { array_push($classargs, $d); }

$form->addElement( new $classname ( ...$classargs ) );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either use the [argument unpacking operator `...`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list):

```
new $classname(...$classargs)
```

Or [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php):

```
(new ReflectionClass($classname))->newInstanceArgs($classargs)
```

Comment: variadic function operator is in the function definition, that is argument unpacking or splat

Comment: Ah right. It doesn't really seem to have an official name besides "... token", which makes it a bit hard to talk about.

Comment: I ended up using the edited code above for anyone who gets here via search.